# Can file_get_contents and file_put_contents interfere when used via Ajax?

Tags: php, file-access

I have a php script which is supposed to read from and write to a certain file (using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`). Now I want to use it with Ajax, so a request to read may arrive when writing is not finished. I suspect that both Unix and Windows have some measures that will prevent a conflict (reading a file, writing which is not finished and vice versa), but I want to be sure.

Could you point if I'm right or wrong and what terms to look for to understand what measures do the file systems have to prevent those conflicts?

Comment: The request that does the writing and reading of a file and the Ajax request are processed completely separate, since they are completely independent http requests. So there is no conflict.

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.txt', $date, LOCK_EX);`

Comment: [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) The file you lock does not have to be the file you are reading writting to/from. You can have a seperate `lock_me.txt` file to control file access to another file.

Comment: @arkascha Surely AJAX calls a PHP script to do the read/write, so conflict is indeed possible

Comment: If every client has it's own file, it may not be a problem. But every ajax call modifies the same file, I suggest using a database.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of restrictions or we don't have a full control over the execution of these 2 functions. My personal suggestion is if your application need concurrent read and write of a file then use PHP file system functions like `fopen`, `fread`, etc.

I hope this helps you.